# Connection refused when using IP but not when using localhost

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat, web, connect

I have deployed my web application in my apache 9 server. I have configured the server following internet guides, and it works fine if I use this link:

```
http://localhost:8080/ejercicios-programacion/
```

which redirects me to

```
https://localhost:8443/ejercicios-programacion/
```

However, if I try to do the same but not using localhost but the IP, for example:

```
http://xx.xxxx.xxxx.xx:8080/ejercicios-programacion/
```

it still redirects me to

```
https://xx.xxxx.xxx.xx:8443/ejercicios-programacion/
```

but I get a "refused to connect" error.

Up until today it was working perfectly both ways, and the only thing I changed was adding ssl security to my webpage, so it most likely has to do with that. Here are my connectors in servers.xml:

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

<Connector port="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:/cert.pfx" keystorePass="defaultpassword" />
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: "apache 9" ? That is a strange version value...

Comment: 9.0.22 but I don't think that matters in this case

Comment: Probably not, but Apache 9 does not exist. Latest version is 2.4.39, see https://httpd.apache.org/

Comment: ok, apache tomcat, not apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to forward the port, that's why my router was refusing the connection, but I had the 8080 port already forwarded so that's why it was still redirecting